# Firebase: Get other children values when i know 1 value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to fetch all other details from a child where i know 1 value of the child [image: I would like to fetch the description and the user]

Kindly assist.
I would like to get the values of the description and the user.
Here is my code;

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1,container,false);
    list = (ListView)  view.findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
    final DatabaseReference rootRef = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final DatabaseReference errandsRef = rootRef.child("Errands");
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(final DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                final String Errand = ds.child("Errand").getValue(String.class);

                ll.add(Errand);
                ListAdapter adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ll);
                //ll.clear();
                list.setAdapter(adp);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        String item = (String) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Kindly assist. Which code should i put inside the onItemClick to fetch the user and the desscription of the item that has been clicked?

Comment: Victor, can you please more specific? Which child do you know and which data would you like to get?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.orderByChild()` and `.equalTo()`. You know the `Errand` of clicked item:

```
String item = (String) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Errands").orderByChild("Errand").equalTo(item).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  //this dataSnapshot is the your object you want
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```